# Parallel.ForEach and Breaking Out After First Result Found

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I'm trying to locate a user in 1 of n "portals" (ultimately a database) and populate a global object based on the user's data. Once the user is found, I need to stop processing. So even if the user is in multiple portals, we only need to use the first one we find him in, order is irrelevant. I'm more curious on whether the approach below is acceptable or if I'm overlooking anything? I'm pretty the queryResult object needs a locking mechanism and any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

```
        bool userFound = false;
        QueryResult queryResult = null;

        // Here, PortalInstance.Map is an IDictionary<int, PortalIntance>
        Parallel.ForEach(PortalInstance.Map, (p, state) =>
            {
                if(userFound)
                {
                    state.Stop();
                }

                PortalInstance p2 = p.Value;
                if(p2 != null)
                {
                    using (SomeWebService svc = new SomeWebService())
                    {
                        string queryText = String.Format("select Id, Email, AccountId from Member where Email = '{0}'", response.Attributes["mail"]);
                        QueryResult qr = svc.Query(queryText);
                        if(qr != null && qr.Records.Length > 0)
                        {
                            queryResult = qr;
                            userFound = true;   
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        if(!userFound)
        {
            throw new Exception("User not found");
        }
```

Edit: With regard to the 'duplicated question' aspect, I'm more interested in whether the above code is sufficient with regard to the global queryResult variable i.e., is it guaranteed that once that value has been set, and the state.Break() method called that another thread can't change it before returning? None of the other questions I've found have addressed that aspect.

Comment: Do you in fact want the result of `Parallel.ForEach(...).First(...)`?

Comment: Yes, perhaps using the First extension method may make things a little easier. However, when using First(), do you know whether it will process all the items in the source collection, or if it breaks out after one has been found and does not attempt to process the remaining items in the collection? I want to keep the number of items processed to the bare minimum.

Comment: It will stop iterating as soon as it can, although there might be other threads in the process of executing which will naturally have to complete. Their results will be ignored, though.